# Modify a PHP validation script to allow cash signs and decimals

Tags: php

I have a PHP script I use to validate a form. Currently it only allows numbers/digits. I have a tried to modify it several ways but it either errors out or gets a 500 error. I would just like to add $ and . in the submission.

Here is the working script that validates numbers only:

```
class Quform_Filter_Digits implements Quform_Filter_Interface
{
    /**
     * Whether to allow white space characters; off by default
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $_allowWhiteSpace = false;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     *
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        if (is_array($options)) {
            if (array_key_exists('allowWhiteSpace', $options)) {
                $this->setAllowWhiteSpace($options['allowWhiteSpace']);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filter everything from the given value except digits
     *
     * @param string $value The value to filter
     * @return string The filtered value
     */
    public function filter($value)
    {
        $whiteSpace = $this->_allowWhiteSpace ? '\s' : '';

        $pattern = '/[^0-9' . $whiteSpace .']/';

        return preg_replace($pattern, '', (string) $value);
    }

    /**
     * Whether or not to allow white space
     *
     * @param boolean $flag
     * @return Quform_Filter_Digits
     */
    public function setAllowWhiteSpace($flag)
    {
        $this->_allowWhiteSpace = (bool) $flag;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Is white space allowed?
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getAllowWhiteSpace()
    {
        return $this->_allowWhiteSpace;
    }
}
```

Comment: @jeroen I just wanted the field to be able to validate money. To allow a $00.00

Comment: @jeroen Sorry they went down for maintenance when I submitted, the entry was gone when they came back up and I quickly started over and copied the wrong file. Then when I clicked on question a few minutes ago, they somehow have the correct draft.  I did however just update this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your regex pattern to allow for more characters:

```
$pattern = '/[^0-9.$' . $whiteSpace .']/';
```

But that would not guarantee a correct order, as `12$.17` for example would pass. An alternative would be to check the first character separately as that is the only one that could be a `$` sign and you would have to decide if it could be a `.`

If you do decide to check the first character separately, you could simply use something like `filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);` on the rest (or including the first character if it is not a dollar sign). See the manual on [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var).

Comment: oh I thought it had to have single quote between them! thanks

Comment: How difficult would it be to adjust it for the correct order?

Comment: I would just check the first character, if it's a `$`, use `filter_var` on the rest and if it's not, use it on the whole string. That would replace your regex completely.

Comment: Ya I was doing it with Jquery before, but I just bought this plugin to replace it and I'm not very good php, as you can tell :)

Comment: @MichaelFalciglia You'd have to do it server-side anyway, but with php's string and filter functions this would work just fine....